# How to fix invalid byte sequence in UTF-8?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

Some times, when uses enter links that have no routes, I present a nice message like:

*Sorry, this link {@not_found_path} was not migrated from our old website, or you've typed it incorrectly ..*

How can I fix the @not_found_path value so that I don't get the error:

`invalid byte sequence in UTF-8` in the template? I have ruby 1.9.3 installed with rails 3.2.11

Any idea?

```
def render_404(exception)
      @not_found_path = exception.message
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render template: 'errors/not_found', layout: 'layouts/application', status: 404 }
        format.all { render nothing: true, status: 404 }
      end
    end
```

Comment: You need to save your views as valid UTF8.

Comment: By configuring your text editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it in the view like this:

```
The link #{content_tag(:span, @not_found_path.force_encoding("ISO-8859-1").encode("utf-8"), :class => 'text-error')} is not found, We are sorry for that, as we have migrated our website, we could not restore all the links.
```

I hope this will help some one